# MySQL, PHP based website statistics

Tags: php, mysql, graph, web-statistics

Trying to integrate something like [tracewatch](http://www.tracewatch.com/) into admin panel of my PHP, MySQL based website.

But I need 1 page solution, not heavy system like twatch with user management.

I wonder, is there any simple php class or mini app for this purpose (want to get something like [this](http://www.dejkam.com/twatch/) on admin page)?

Comment: Question for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 4):

There are bunch of tracewatch alternatives. Here are somes:

## [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)

[image]

Piwik is an open-source Web analytics application developed using PHP and MySQL. It has a "plugins" system that allows for utmost extensibility and customization. Install only the plugins you need or go overboard and install them all – the choice is up to you. The plugins system, as you can imagine, also opens up possibilities for you to create your own custom extensions. This thing’s lightweight – the download’s only 1.9MB.

## [FireStats](http://firestats.cc/)

[image]

FireStats is a simple and straight-forward Web analytics application written in PHP/MySQL. It supports numerous platforms and set-ups including C# sites, Django sites, Drupal, Joomla!, WordPress, and several others. Are you a resourceful developer who needs moar cowbell? FireStats has an excellent API that will assist you in creating your own custom apps or publishing platform components (imagine: displaying the top 10 most downloaded files in your WordPress site) based on your FireStats data.

## [JAWStats](http://www.jawstats.com/)

[image]

JAWStats is a server-based Web analytics application that runs with the popular AWStats (in fact, if you’re on a shared hosting plan – AWStats is probably already installed). JAWStats does two things to extend AWStats – it improves performance by reducing server resource usage and improves the user interface a little bit. With that said, you can’t go wrong with just using AWStats either if you’re happy with it.

## [SimpleStats](http://stats.simplepublisher.com/)

[image]

Simple Stats is a PHP based, web analytics utility designed to enable you in monitoring visits on your website. It is very simple to install, and it's interface goes straight to the important facts such as the Google search queries (understand "the search expressions in Google") that your visitors might have used to browse to your website.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Piwik](http://piwik.org/). You can access features using an API or embed a widget via iframe.